# Access latest state in useMemo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-usememo

I am using `react-quill`, and it's requirement is that `modules` prop must be cached and shouldn't change. I am using `useMemo` hook to memoize it. The object is:

```
const modules = useMemo(() => ({
  key: {
    value: {
      handler: handlerFunc
    }
  }), [])
```

and it's used like:

```
<Quill
  modules={modules}
  value={value}
  onChange={onChange}
  // value and onChange are props
/>
```

`handleFunc` in `modules` object, just console logs `value` prop. **The issue is that `value` is not latest, it's the first value.** I tried same thing in class component and I was able to get the value and it works perfectly fine, but unfortunately it doesn't work with `useMemo`. Please note, I can't just put `[value]` in second argument of `useMemo` as `modules` shouldn't be changed.

#### Class component implementation:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.handlerFunc = this.handlerFunc.bind(this)
    this.modules = this.initModules(this.handlerFunc)
  }

  initModules(handlerFunc) {
    return {
      key: {
        value: {
          handler: handlerFunc,
        },
      },
    }
  }

  handlerFunc() {
    console.log(this.props.value)
  }
}
```

But I can't use class-component as it's a requirement to use functional-components only. Is there any way, I can have latest `value` in `useMemo`, or yet any other solution?

Comment: _The issue is that value is not latest, it's the first value._ - yes because you don't change the function. That's what memoizing does. Put `value` in the `useMemo` dependency array, but then you should know that the function will update when `value` does.

Comment: I know, do you have any other solution?

Comment: You have a conflict of concerns. Which is more important? The function should not change, or that it should change to have the latest `value` value?

Comment: I need exact implementation of class component. Why it's the latest value in class component? Even though I am assigning a static value in constructor, same like `useMemo` and it's not changing. But still I can access latest value in there, but not in `useMemo`.

Comment: It's not changing _because_ you're using `useMemo`. Please read their docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Comment: Just remove "useMemo", not familar with quill but is there problem after removing "useMemo"? From the documentation it's bit strange as modules doesn't seem to have key attributes as written, only certain objects like history/toolbar/keyboards are accepted.

Comment: I have just pasted dummy options, and regarding removing `useMemo` check [this](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1940#issuecomment-379536850).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are not assigning a `ref` to the editor and getting the value from it, instead of having it from `value` prop?

```
const editor = this.reactQuillRef.getEditor();
editor.getText(); // getText, getHTML or whatever
```

Here's the [link](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill#methods)